# Navigate an array of functions by click

Tags: jquery, function, onclick

I have two buttons (next and back), and I want to execute the next function of an array every time "next" is clicked, and perform the last, when "back" is clicked with jquery. I don`t know where to start...

```
function1 ();
function2 ();
function3 ();
function4 ();
```

Comment: What should happen if `next` is clicked and the last executed function was 4? Start all over?

Comment: Yes! It will start all over.

Answer (score 1):

You could put those functions into an array:

```
var functions = [ function1, function2, function3, function4 ];
```

and have an integer to keep track of the last executed function:

```
var index = 0;
```

Now when next is clicked you would invoke the function at the specified index in the array and increment it:

```
functions[Math.abs(index % functions.length)]();
index++;
```

When back is clicked do the same but decrement the index:

```
functions[Math.abs(index % functions.length)]();
index--;
```

The `index % functions.length` ensures that the returned value is always within the `0-3` range which is actually the allowed index range for your array.

Comment: If I don`t want to start it over, how is it look like?

Comment: What do you want to happen if not start over?

Comment: Just go to the last function with "next", and the "back"  will comeback one function.